# A question about geodesic curvature and covariant acceleration of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

In Eberhard Zeidler's Quantum Filed Theory III two equivalent definition about geodesic curvature was given:
$$ \kappa_{\rm g}(s)
=\cfrac{D\dot x(s)}{{\rm d}s}\cdot(n\times\dot x(s))
=\left< \cfrac{D\dot x(s)}{{\rm d}t}\middle|J\dot x(s) \right> $$
where $\cfrac{D\dot x(s)}{{\rm d}s}$ is covariant acceleration, $n$ the outer unit normal vector , $s$ the arc length and $J$ a rotation operator around $n$ about the angle $\pi/2$. Following that $\dot x(s)$ and $n$ are both unit vector he gave a result that
$$|\kappa_{\rm g}|=\left| \cfrac{D\dot x(s)}{{\rm d}t} \right| $$
meaning that the geodesic curvature measures the strength of the covariant acceleration. However, in my opinion, though $n$ and $\dot x(s)$ are both unit and so does $n\times\dot x(s)$, to say $|\kappa_{\rm g}|=\left| \cfrac{D\dot x(s)}{{\rm d}t} \right| $ we should keep that the direction of $ \cfrac{D\dot x(s)}{{\rm d}t} $ be parallel with $J\dot x(s)$ or equivalently, perpendicular to $\dot x(s)$. So it's just a special case.

Did I made a correct observation? Would there exists a theorem that $ \cfrac{D\dot x(s)}{{\rm d}t} $ must be perpendicular to $\dot x(s)$ ? How do everyone see this?

[The original text in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iORhg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct (except some of the $t$'s in your post should be $s$). By arclength parametrization, we have the magnitude of the velocity is covariantly constant, i. e., $D/ds(\langle \dot{x}(s) | \dot{x}(s) \rangle) = 0$.

Now, use the product rule to expand this out, symmetry of the inner product, and you get your desired orthogonality.

Comment: Thanks for you solving my problem. I think, for $D/ds(\left<\dot x(s) \middle|\dot x(s) \right)=0$, it is only established when the result of inner product is a constant number, but there might be many circumstances that the result is a function. How about this observation？

Comment: Arclength parametrization means that the speed is identically equal to $1$.